# How to parse data from request posted by Mailgun? C#

Tags: c#, parsing, mailgun, email-bounces

I am trying to get data from the posted request by Mailgun for bounced emails and put it in an error log. However, I can't find a way to do this.

The request from mailgun looks like this:

```
--127.0.0.1.1001.72643.1217418299.480.49
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="domain"

beta.mysite.mailgun.org
--127.0.0.1.1001.72643.1217418299.480.49
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="code"

605
--127.0.0.1.1001.72643.1217418299.480.49
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="description"

Not delivering to previously bounced address
--127.0.0.1.1001.72643.1217418299.480.49
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="my_var_1"

Mailgun Variable #1
--127.0.0.1.1001.72643.1217418299.480.49
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="reason"

hardfail
--127.0.0.1.1001.72643.1217418299.480.49
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="my-var-2"

awesome
```

and I want my Errorlogfile.txt to have something like this:

```
domain: beta.mysite.mailgun.org
code: 605
description: Not delivering to previously bounced address
my_var_1: Mailgun Variable #1
reason: hardfail
my-var-2: awesome
```

I don't know if my question is clear so please ask me for clarifications if there's any. Tnx!

Answer (score 0):

If the message pattern repeats with the same order for each message groups, then it may be easy to create a parser that processes the messages and generates the text you want in the format you want. Let me know if you are creating an app in C# for this. If so, I can write you some code to accomplish your task.

Comment: Yeah i'm already considering this but i thought that because this is posted by mailgun, that there is already a way to do so without having to create my own parser. Is that the only way?

Comment: I don't know if there is an existing parser, but I'd be happy to write a quick parser for you. Please send me a larger log sample via my gmail account, which is the same as my username here.